# Ambiguous value error using .isna().all()

Tags: python, pandas

I've written some code to pull a list of columns that are empty from a pandas dataframe. The code pulls all of the excel files from a directory and iterates through each one, and a separate empty column list is created for each. However, for some tables I get this:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I can't for the life of me figure out why it happens on only some tables. There are no duplicate column names.

```
data = [[a, b, c, d],[q, r, s, t],[],[w, x, y, z]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Full_1', 'Full_2', 'Empty', 'Full_3']


def lister(df):
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].isna().all():
        return lst.append(df.columns[c])
    else:
        nope = 'None'
        return nope
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Having This problem because `isna()` returning a series of `boolen` values

use this:-

```
def lister(df):
    lst = []
    for c in df.columns:
        if (df[c].isna().max()) == True:
            lst.append(c)
    return lst
```

Now if you call the function :-`lister()` and pass your dataframe `df` to it you will get your desired output

```
lister(df)

Output:-
['Full_1', 'Full_2', 'Empty', 'Full_3']
```